# Prevent user from accessing previous page using back button after logout

Tags: logout, elixir, phoenix-framework

Using the Phoenix framework, how to stop user from accessing the previous pages once he/she logs out and presses browser back button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser can access the page because it is allowed to cache the response by default. If you want to prevent that, you need to set the appropriate HTTP headers on the pages that require authentication, as per [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers):

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

You could do this in a Plug

```
defmodule MyApp.PreventCaching do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(options) do
    options
  end

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    conn
    |> put_resp_header("cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
    |> put_resp_header("pragma", "no-cache")
    |> put_resp_header("expires", "0")
  end
end
```

Then in your router (or controller), you can use the plug to set the headers on all pages that require authentication

```
plug MyApp.PreventCaching
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention Patrick Oscity, this is the answer for my question, i will put my code here if any person want to prevent that

Comment: Improving the answer a little bit.
From [Mozzila docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) a good response header should be
`Cache-Control: no-store`
instead of 
`Cache-Control: private,no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate,pre-check=0,post-check=0`

Comment: @zegomesjf in an ideal world, where all browsers stick to the spec, yes. In practice though various browsers have their own quirks and disrespect the RFC, so we end up needing ugly things like this. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers

Comment: Looks like you are already piping the `conn` as a first_parameter. So, no need to pass again inside `put_resp_header`.